# How to show patch coordinates in plabels Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to display the x-coordinates and y-coordinates of the netlogo world when a button is clicked.I have used below code.But it gives an error.How do I do this??

```
ask patches with [pxcor mod 5 = 0 and pycor mod 5 = 0] 
[
 set plabel  pxcor  pycor 
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `pxcor pycor` to `(word "(" pxcor "," pycor ")")`